# Use re (regular expression) to parse all lines before a string

Tags: python, regex

I'm a scientist trying to use Python to parse data from my research. I'm using the **re** module to do some treatment before converting my data to a pandas dataframe.

So far, I was able to achieve what I want with this code:

```
with open("nq1a.dd2", "r") as dd2_all_input_lines:
        for dd2_line in dd2_all_input_lines:
            if "alternative" in dd2_line:
                break
            else:
                dd2_valid_lines = dd2_line  # It stops before the string "alternative" is found, that is what I want.
```

But I'd like to ask if there is a way to tell **re** to get all lines before the string "alternative" is found instead of using **IF** like I did.

```
VALID LIVES
....
VALID LINES
<keyword here> (Stop here!)
INVALID LINES
....
INVALID LINES
```

Thank you so much.

**Sample Data**

```
s 91    1.00   OUT     9    3   12    7   OCCC     0.34  f829 27  f752 33
       -1.00          10    6   11    8   OCCC     0.74
s 92    1.00   OUT    13    8   12   11   ClCCC     1.98  f284 55  f172 13
s 93    1.00   OUT    30   19   20   16   OCCC     0.17  f864 14  f746 11  f535 17  f517 11
s 94    1.00   OUT     7    6    1    3   CCCC     0.48  f829 10  f172 41
       -1.00           8    3    2    6   CCCC     1.09
s 95    1.00   OUT    17   14   18   15   CNCC     3.64  f564 16  f535 15  f396 10
s 96    1.00   OUT    10    6   11    8   OCCC     0.74  f822 63
       -1.00           8    2    3    6   CCCC     1.09
        1.00           9    3   12    7   OCCC     0.34
****
 33 STRE modes:
  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33
 32 BEND modes:
 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53
 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65
 31 TORS modes:
 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85
 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96
 33 CH modes:
  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46
 47 48 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77
 0 USER modes:


alternative coordinates 118 
k 34    1.00   STRE   20   16   CC    1.396055
k 35    1.00   STRE    6    3   CC    1.394020
k 36    1.00   STRE    7   12   CC    1.518475
v 36    1.00   BEND    7    3    6   CCC   119.99
k 37    1.00   BEND   21   14   12   HNC   111.99
k 38    1.00   BEND   22    1    3   HCC   119.07
k 39    1.00   BEND   25    2    5   HCC   121.23
k 40    1.00   BEND   23    4    5   HCC   120.11
k 41    1.00   BEND   24    5    4   HCC   119.93
k 42    1.00   BEND   28   17   15   HCC   119.54
k 43    1.00   BEND   27   18   15   HCC   119.88
k 44    1.00   BEND   26   19   16   HCC   121.15
k 45    1.00   BEND   29   20   16   HCC   118.64
k 46    1.00   BEND   32   31   30   HCO   111.30
k 47    1.00   BEND   33   31   30   HCO   111.27
k 48    1.00   BEND   34   31   32   HCH   109.33
k 49    1.00   BEND    9    7    3   OCC   122.75
k 50    1.00   BEND   10    8    6   OCC   120.23
k 51    1.00   BEND    7   12   11   CCC   118.96
k 55    1.00   BEND    6    3    1   CCC   120.39
k 58    1.00   BEND   20   16   19   CCC   119.50
k 59    1.00   BEND   17   15   14   CCN   118.88
k 60    1.00   BEND   30   16   19   OCC   124.53
k 63    1.00   BEND    8    6    3   CCC   121.15
k 65    1.00   BEND   13   11   12   ClCC   121.99
k 66    1.00   TORS   21   14   15   18   HNCC  -240.27
k 66    1.00   TORS   21   14   12    7   HNCC    -5.99
k 66    1.00   OUT    14   12   15   21   NCCH     5.36
k 67    1.00   TORS   22    1    3    6   HCCC  -179.92
k 67    1.00   TORS   22    1    4   23   HCCH     0.05
k 67    1.00   OUT     1    3    4   22   CCCH     0.09
k 68    1.00   TORS   25    2    5    4   HCCC  -179.54
k 68    1.00   TORS   25    2    6    8   HCCC     0.99
k 68    1.00   OUT     2    5    6   25   CCCH     0.08
k 69    1.00   TORS   23    4    5    2   HCCC  -180.07
k 69    1.00   OUT     4    5    1   23   CCCH     0.02
k 70    1.00   TORS   24    5    4   23   HCCH     0.07
k 70    1.00   TORS   24    5    4    1   HCCC  -180.00
k 70    1.00   OUT     5    4    2   24   CCCH     0.05
k 71    1.00   TORS   28   17   15   14   HCCN    -3.77
k 71    1.00   TORS   28   17   15   18   HCCC  -179.70
k 71    1.00   OUT    17   15   20   28   CCCH     0.12
k 72    1.00   TORS   27   18   15   14   HCCN     2.71
k 72    1.00   TORS   27   18   19   26   HCCH     0.54
k 72    1.00   OUT    18   15   19   27   CCCH     0.03
k 73    1.00   TORS   26   19   16   30   HCCO     0.41
k 73    1.00   TORS   26   19   16   20   HCCC  -179.39
k 73    1.00   OUT    19   16   18   26   CCCH     0.21
k 74    1.00   TORS   29   20   17   28   HCCH     0.25
k 74    1.00   TORS   29   20   16   19   HCCC  -180.23
k 74    1.00   OUT    20   16   17   29   CCCH     0.16
k 75    1.00   OUT    31   34   33   32   CHHH    19.50
k 75    1.00   OUT    31   32   33   34   CHHH    19.61
k 75    1.00   OUT    31   34   32   33   CHHH    19.50
k 76    1.00   OUT    31   32   30   33   CHOH    19.77
k 76    1.00   OUT    31   33   30   32   CHOH    19.77
k 76    1.00   OUT    31   32   33   30   CHHO    15.09
k 77    1.00   OUT    31   32   30   34   CHOH    21.84
k 77    1.00   OUT    31   33   30   34   CHOH    21.84
k 78    1.00   TORS    7   12   11    8   CCCC    -6.67
k 79    1.00   TORS   16   20   17   15   CCCC     0.37
k 79    1.00   TORS   20   17   15   18   CCCC     0.66
k 79    1.00   TORS   17   20   16   19   CCCC    -0.70
k 80    1.00   TORS    2    6    3    1   CCCC    -0.24
k 82    1.00   TORS    6    3    1    4   CCCC     0.33
k 82    1.00   TORS    3    7   12   11   CCCC     6.53
k 83    1.00   TORS    3    6    2    5   CCCC    -0.04
k 86    1.00   TORS   20   16   19   18   CCCC    -0.01
k 87    1.00   TORS   11    8    6    2   CCCC  -179.10
k 89    1.00   TORS   31   30   16   20   COCC  -179.96
k 90    1.00   OUT     8    6   11   10   CCCO     0.28
k 90    1.00   TORS   10    8   11   12   OCCC  -178.42
k 90    1.00   TORS   10    8   11   13   OCCCl     3.77
k 91    1.00   OUT     7    3   12    9   CCCO     0.13
k 91    1.00   TORS    9    7   12   11   OCCC  -173.85
k 91    1.00   TORS    9    7   12   14   OCCN     3.26
k 92    1.00   OUT    11    8   12   13   CCCCl     0.55
k 92    1.00   TORS   13   11   12    7   ClCCC  -189.01
k 92    1.00   TORS   13   11   12   14   ClCCN    -5.50
k 93    1.00   OUT    16   19   20   30   CCCO     0.06
k 93    1.00   TORS   30   16   19   18   OCCC  -180.21
k 93    1.00   TORS   30   16   20   17   OCCC  -180.51
k 94    1.00   OUT     3    6    1    7   CCCC     0.15
k 94    1.00   TORS    7    3    6    8   CCCC    -2.07
k 94    1.00   TORS    7    3    1    4   CCCC  -179.12
k 95    1.00   OUT    15   14   18   17   CNCC     1.20
k 95    1.00   TORS   17   15   18   19   CCCC    -1.37
k 95    1.00   TORS   17   15   14   12   CCNC  -219.68
k 96    1.00   OUT     6    3    2    8   CCCC     0.35
k 96    1.00   TORS    8    6    2    5   CCCC  -178.79
k 96    1.00   TORS    8    6    3    1   CCCC  -181.52
v 9     1.00   STRE   20   16   CC    1.396055
v 15    1.00   STRE    7   12   CC    1.518475
v 20    1.00   STRE    6    3   CC    1.394020
v 22    1.00   STRE    6    3   CC    1.394020
v 25    1.00   STRE   20   16   CC    1.396055
v 29    1.00   STRE    7   12   CC    1.518475
v 34    1.00   BEND   16   20   17   CCC   120.33
v 35    1.00   BEND    3    6    2   CCC   119.61
v 36    1.00   BEND   12    7    3   CCC   118.82
v 82    1.00   TORS    1    3    6    2   CCCC    -0.24
v 84    1.00   TORS   19   16   20   17   CCCC    -0.70
v 87    1.00   TORS   11   12    7    3   CCCC     6.53
s 27    1.00   STRE   30   16   OC    1.355049
s 24    1.00   STRE   14   12   NC    1.344852
s 57    1.00   BEND   14   12   11   NCC   129.85
s 62    1.00   BEND   15   14   12   CNC   130.10
s 59    1.00   BEND   17   15   18   CCC   119.42
s 54    1.00   BEND   18   15   14   CCN   121.57
```

Comment: Can you add some sample data and expected outputs?

Comment: If `if` works, why not sure `if`?

Comment: I'm sorry if my question is no clear, maybe my bad coding turns it worse to understand. I just want to parse all the lines above a string and then stop the parsing.

Comment: It's not bad code. Your solution looks fine to me, although I have to imagine what the data looks like. I guess there are lines like "s  123  something"  "s  324  something else" up to "alternative".

Comment: @Bemmu you're right, the lines I'm interested are starting with s 123. I've added a sample.

Comment: @HenriqueJunior your approach is perfectly valid. If however, you had an enormous dataset, and you wanted to be as _efficient as possible_, then you could consider loading the file as a binary blob and searching for the bytes that match "alternative". You could then split the blob at this point and continue parsing the first part of the blob as you have done here, without having to worry about matching the string anymore because you know the file was already split. This however would be marginally faster, at best, and quite complex (relatively speaking), so is very hard to justify.

Comment: Thank you, @RichardDunn, I was worried that my approach could be the "dumb" way to tackle the problem. Since I'm just a beginner it is good to know that I got it right.